# Pointer at last word

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to return a pointer to the last word in a string.

Example: "the sky is blue" - it should return "blue".

But I'm having problems when I have space after the string:

Example: "the sky is blue   " - it returns ' '.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
const char* function(const char *s)
{
   char *l;
   int length=strlen(s);

    l=(char *)(s+length-1);
    while(l!=s)
    {
        if(*l==' ')
        break;

        l--;
    }
    if(l!=s)
    return l+1;
}
```

Comment: You could add a pre-loop that simply skips past trailing spaces.  Then you can enter your main loop.  Also, at the end you test if `l != s`, and is so, you return `l+1`.  Otherwise, you don't return anything, which means the caller will pick up some random garbage value.  Don't do that.

Comment: @TomKarzes I've added this loop, but I don't understand why it's not working correctly?
` while(*l!=' ')
    {
        if(isspace((unsigned char *)l))
        l--;
    }
   `

Comment: "I'm having problems" doesn't really adequately describe your understanding of the situation.  Do you understand _why_ your code produces the results it does (even if they are not your intended/expected results)?  Are you absolutely convinced that your code is correct and can discuss why?  Have you used a debugger to debug your application step-by-step?  I feel like it's straightforward to understand why your code will return `" "` if the last character of the string is a space.  So do you understand why?

Comment: What should happen with trailing tabs and newlines?  It seems likely that you'd need to skip backwards over trailing characters that match `isspace()` from `<ctype.h>`, and then skip backwards over non-spaces until the next space, or the start of the string.

Comment: When you get the pointer to the "last word", you need to think about when/where potential trailing whitespace may (or may not) be truncated.

Comment: @user20941117 Your pre-loop `while` test is backwards.  `while (*l != ' ') ...` will exit immediately if the last character is a space.  Use `==` instead.  Reason it out.

Answer (score 1):

The loop `while(*l!=' ') {if(isspace((unsigned char *)l)) l--; }` is not working because `if(isspace((unsigned char *)l)) l--;` will be executed only `while(*l!=' ')`: but if the string's last character is a space, then `*l==' '`, which means you are just skipping the loop.
Then the correct cycle could be : `while(*l==' ') {if(isspace((unsigned char *)l)) l--; }`

Your original code instead returns an empty character because you point l to the latest character in the string, then when you enter the `while` cycle, it just exit at the first iteration because `*l==' '` and then you just break the cycle.
You could just move `l--;` before the `if(*l==' ') break;` instruction, but you will have the same problem when you have two or more spaces.

You could even do something simple as the following code, this will return the latest word, digit or punctuation character in the string:

```
const char* function(const char *s){
    char *l=(char*)(s+strlen(s)-1);
    while(isspace(*l)) l--;
    while(isdigit(*l)||iscntrl(*l)||ispunct(*l)) l--;
    while(isalnum(*l)) l--;
    return l+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There are executions of your `function` that doesn't return a value.  This is undefined behavior I believe.
2. Your code is poorly formatted, and `function` is a particular confusing choice of name.
3. You break if `l` pointers to a space and then return `l + 1` which would be the terminating '\0' in your sample data.

First let's define the delimiter, then skip over the initial ones so we start with a word.  Then we find the next delimiter and skip the those if we fail to find a delimiter or we are at the end of the input then we return the last word we found.   If the input doesn't contain any words the output is an empty string.

```
#define DELIM " "
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* function(const char *s) {
    if(!s) return NULL;
    while(*s && strchr(DELIM, *s)) s++;
    for(;;) {
        const char *last = s;
        s = strpbrk(s, DELIM);
        while(s && *s && strchr(DELIM, *s)) s++;
        if(!s || !*s) return last;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf("\"%s\"\n", function("the sky is blue "));
}
```

example session:

```
"blue "
```

Note the trailing space.  You either have to give up the `const` of the input or you have to make a copy if the last word so you strip trailing space(s).